# Hibernate query.uniqueResult() throws NonUniqueResultException, but the record is Unique

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a `Client` class, which is in one-to-many with `ClientCurrency` which is in one-to-one with `PaymentRule`.

```
  @Entity(name = "Client")
  public class Client{
    ...
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
     @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
     @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
     public Set<ClientCurrency> getClientCurrencies() {
         return clientCurrencies;
     }
    }

  @Entity(name = "Client_Currency")
  public class ClientCurrency{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    @Column(name = "currency", length = 3)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    }
```

Where `Currency` - is Enum with some currencies.
Now I'm trying to get a `ClientCurrency` with this method:

```
    public ClientCurrency get(Client client, Currency currency) {
        StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder().append("FROM ")
                .append(ClientCurrency.class.getName())
                .append(" WHERE client = :client AND currency = :currency");
        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(hql.toString()).setParameter("client", client)
                .setParameter("currency", currency);
        return (ClientCurrency)query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

I know that the record is unique in database. I tried with `query.list()` and it returns two duplicates. Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Why your getClientCurrencies() method in Client returns set of Clients?

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski it was a typo, thanks.

Comment: Double check your equals() method for Client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why your query is returning a duplicate, but you should be able to get around it by writing your query like this: `"SELECT DISTINCT c FROM <CC.class.getName()> c ..."` (similar to how you'd do it in SQL).